# How to create my own EC2 AMI with a custom distro and a custom kernel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I would like to create my own custom AMI with its own custom kernel running on a HVM instance.

At first I thought this is a solved problem as I've seen several solution out there, (packer, aminate),
that solve this kind of problem, however none of them was not flexible enough for my own needs,
all of these solutions were also automating the upload stage along with machine creation,
my pipeline is already doing that along with other stages that are complex and complete,
I am only looking to create a custom image and a custom HVM kernel, I will upload the image with
my own infrastructure and AWS EC2 SDK.

I would like to create my own custom EC2 AMI with my own custom kernel, I've seen AWS is using 5.4 and 4.14 branches and I can compile my own kernel but I'm not sure how to pack things properly.

Can anyone guide me to the appropriate steps in order to create such image?

Comment: Answering myself here, AWS originally offers ami cli tools, however they are old and I did not manage to find a modern version, I could only find version 1.5.7 20071010 which uses certificates as your id. Nowadays, (2020 and probably since 2015?~), AWS has a KeyId and Secret Access Id which are 2 strings that are not a certificate. This made ec2-create-bundle useless as  one of the arguments there requires the certificate to be a secret. Specifically, the process that ec2-create-bundle does is: tar the image, gzip it and encrypt it with the secret certificate using AES CBC mode.

Comment: this process is not possible today! however, IT IS POSSIBLE to import a raw disk image, (or a vmdk, or an ova), create a snapshot from it and THEN CREATE AMI FROM IT

Comment: Creating a custom AMI along with a custom AKI is easypz, just debootstrap a system, add your SSH keys and mount it. MAKE SURE TO USE "/dev/xvda1" as a kernel command line argument since the volumes are xv, (xen specific iirc), based!